# Trapezium navigation menu mouse interaction

Tags: css, html

I have designed a navigation menu which uses trapeziums instead of rectangles. I have got something working but it doesn't behave properly. I have tried using a negative left margin of `-15px` to offset the link but this doesn't appear to work.

The following illustration demonstrates what I have working along with that desired. Given the same cursor position "Brokerage" should be highlighted instead of "Services" (with hover or click).

How can I fix this? Is there a better way to achieve this (baring in mind that I want compatibility with IE7+)

[image: Illustration of current and desired behaviour]

Here is the HTML structure of the navigation menu:

```
<nav>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Brokerage</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li class="first current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
nav ul li {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-left: -30px;
    line-height: 69px;

    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16pt;

    background: url(img/nav.png) no-repeat right -69px;
}
nav ul li:hover {
    background: url(img/nav.png) no-repeat right -207px;
}
nav ul li.current {
    background: url(img/nav.png) no-repeat right 0px;
}
nav ul li.current:hover {
    background: url(img/nav.png) no-repeat right -138px;
}

nav ul li.first a {
    background: url(img/nav.png) no-repeat left bottom;
}
nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 26pt;

    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: #4e649f;
}
nav ul li:hover a {
    color: #9e4e4e !important;
}
nav ul li.current a {
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

Here is the img/nav.png image, please note that bottom strip of image contains a white triangle that is used to cover start of first navigation item.

[image: Image used for navigation items]

^-----^ White triangle here - remainder is transparent (PNG-24)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there are at least three solutions of which two use javascript:

#### Imagemap + hover event

You could use a transparent imagemap that lies over the navigation and use the href attribute on the area tags. The areas could be trapezoids like your navigation items.

#### RaphaelJS

You could use RaphaelJS to draw shapes over the navigation and bind to mouseover/click events.

#### Plain Javascript

You could just calculate the position of the cursor and trigger the appropriate link with plain javascript.

Comment: If I go with RaphaelJS are there going to be any compatibility issues with web browsers? Are plugins going to be required for SVG support?

Comment: RaphaelJS is a very stable library, which has long time support for all major browsers. From the website: Raphaël currently supports Firefox 3.0+, Safari 3.0+, Chrome 5.0+, Opera 9.5+ and Internet Explorer 6.0+.

Comment: cheers after some experimentation I have come to the conclusion that Plain Javascript is the best solution. If JavaScript is enabled additional DIV elements are created and positioned as desired. They automatically trigger state changes on underlying elements. Nice thing with this approach is that new menu items can be added without having to worry about changing the JavaScript also. And it still works even if JavaScript is disabled, just less accurate clicking.

Comment: thanks again, I have added a JavaScript implementation example to your answer for the benefit of future readers